# Grunt Multitask configuration issues

Tags: gruntjs

I'm trying to configure a grunt file that can run multiple tasks on multiple "themes". Since i'm new to this whole grunt thing, i'm having some problems with the configuration.

My example below is just a start, but essentially I'd like to have some global configs, and then nest specific "theme" configurations within a named "target". I'm not fully up to speed on syntax, so that could be the issue, but when I run `grunt powerful` I get the error **Warning: Required config property "watch" missing**? I feel that the configs are ok, but the problem lies with my `registerMultiTask`. Any ideas?

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

// Project configuration.

grunt.initConfig({

    // Metadata.
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    banner: '/*!\n' +
        '* Microsites v<%= pkg.version %>\n' +
        '* Copyright <%= grunt.template.today("yyyy") %> <%= pkg.author %>\n' +
        '*/\n' +
        '/* @package: <%= pkg.name %> */\n',
    jqueryCheck: 'if (!jQuery) { throw new Error(\"<%= pkg.name %> requires jQuery\") }\n\n',
    basePath: '../../www/wp-content/themes',

    powerful: {
        name:   'Powerful Theme',
        path:   '<%= basePath %>/powerful',
        less: {
            development: {
                options: {
                    dumpLineNumbers: true
                },
                files: {
                    '<%= powerful.path %>/static/css/project.css':  '<%= powerful.path %>/static/css/less/project.less',
                    '<%= powerful.path %>/static/css/editor.css':   '<%= powerful.path %>/static/css/less/editor.less',
                    '<%= powerful.path %>/static/css/login.css':    '<%= powerful.path %>/static/css/less/login.less'
                }
            },
            production: {
                options: {
                    yuicompress: true
                },
                files: {
                    '<%= powerful.path %>/static/css/project.css':  '<%= powerful.path %>/static/css/less/project.less',
                    '<%= powerful.path %>/static/css/editor.css':   '<%= powerful.path %>/static/css/less/editor.less',
                    '<%= powerful.path %>/static/css/login.css':    '<%= powerful.path %>/static/css/less/login.less'
                }
            },
            ie: {
                options: {
                    yuicompress: true
                },
                files: {
                    '<%= powerful.path %>/static/css/ie.css':       '<%= powerful.path %>/static/css/less/ie.less'
                }
            }
        },
        watch: {
            less: {
                files: ['<%= powerful.path %>/static/css/less/*.less'],
                tasks: ['less:development']
            }
        }
    }, // end: powerful

});


// load the plugin
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-less');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');

// load tasks
//grunt.registerTask('default', ['less']);
grunt.registerMultiTask('powerful', 'do things', function(){
    grunt.task.run(['watch']);
});
};
```

Comment: @Kyle Robinson Young - After playing around it seems you're right, I can't configure things the way I posted. Ultimately what i'd like is to have on gruntfile that I can run different tasks on different folders. Less tasks are able to specify subtasks (dev, prod, etc) so I'd like to able to do something similar with uglify and other tasks too. Possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tasks should go on the first level of your config, not within another task config. Also your `powerful` task isnt a multitask so it doesnt even need a config block. Just configure the tasks the standard way:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  less: {
    /* config here */
  },
  watch: {
    /* config here */
  }
});
```